# Matlab large rows in Anonymous Functions

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

In the Matlab Anonymous Functions, I want to have Functions fun_total like this

```
fun_total = @(x) [ 0;
               1*x(1);
               1*x(1);
               2*x(2);
               2*x(2);
               ...
               100000*x(100000);
               100000*x(100000);]
```

so here is my code

```
fun_total = @(x) [0];
for i = 1 : 100000
  fun_temp = @(x) i*x(i);
  fun_total = @(x) [ fun_total(x); fun_temp(x) ];
  fun_total = @(x) [ fun_total(x); fun_temp(x) ];
end
```

My problem is it's too slow when loop iteration become bigger. 
Every time  fun_total = @(x) [ fun_total(x); fun_temp(x) ];
The fun_total(x) will expand first ,and then merge.

Now I have a solution is output my fun_total as a text file,
and then change to function. 
Is this can work? or someone have other efficient solution? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem obviously is, that you are generating 100000 anonymous functions `fun_temp` (and 100000 nested functions `fun_total`). This is essentially the same as generating all the m-file-functions 
`function result=xTimes1(x)`, `function result=xTimes2(x)`, `function result=xTimes3(x)`,... Which when you look at it that way is totally absurd. The best solution is certainly going with a vectorized solution like *Dan*'s, but you can also always consider using a single m-function file.

In terms of efficiency you should expect this hierarchy:

> Lots of (anonymous) function calls < lots of `for`-loop iterations <
>   vectorized code.

So as an intermediate step to the vectorized solution you could use:

```
function total = fun_total(x)
total = zeros(2*length(x)+1,1);
for i = 1:length(x)
    total([2*i,2*i+1]) = [i*x(i); i*x(i)];
end
```

and then generate the function handle using `@fun_total`.

Comment: specially for the hierarchy: +1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
fun_total = @(x)reshape(repmat(1:numel(x).*x, 2, 1),[],1)
```

or

```
fun_total = @(x)reshape([1;1]*(1:numel(x).*x),[],1)
```